# "kept afloat" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Most programming projects are kept afloat by the best programmers on the team.

I don't understand this sentence. I found "afloat" to have meaning of "floating on water" which does not suit in this sentence. Am I using the wrong definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are looking at the wrong definition.

> [afloat](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/afloat)
>   6. free of major trouble, especially financially solvent:
>   to keep a venture afloat.
>   (Dictionary.com)

The best programmers keep the projects viable. Without them, the projects would be in trouble and likely fail.

You can think of *afloat* metaphorically by considering the project to be a ship. If it is afloat, then it is safe. If it is not afloat, then it is sinking and in serious trouble.

Comment: Yeah, the literal term became a metaphor when applied to financial matters, and has generalized from there to refer to any "support" that is somewhat "unnatural" or non-obvious.